# how to display nested dictionary in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

how can i display them using angularjs ngRepeat.

results: {
    "keshvica": {
      "google": 4, 
      "sbi": 0
    }, 
    "pragti": {
      "facebook": 3, 
      "vogella": 5, 
      "wikipedia": 1
    }
}

Comment: provide your complete scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in dict">
         {{key}} : {{value}} 
       <div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value">
        {{key1}} : {{value1}} 
       </div>
 </div>
```

where

```
$scope.dict = { "keshvica": { "google": 4, "sbi": 0 }, "pragti": { "facebook": 3, "vogella": 5, "wikipedia": 1 } }
```

Comment: INFO: this way it will be sorted alphabetically prior to angular 1.4 (where this will be resolved, finally)